# Can we draw a line chart over GroupedStackedBarChart

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am trying to create a `GroupedStackBar` chart which shows revenue for each client for past three months for each product and add line chart(s) depicting the meetings done with the client over each period. I am using JasperReports to create a PDF report using the usual Chart customizers to prep it.

The below snapshot surmises the chart I am trying to create:

[image: chart image].

The report needs to portray monthly revenues and meetings for each client. As in, show that `Client1` provided for `X` mn in revenues and had `M`meetings in Nov, `Y` mn in revenues and `N` meetings in Dec and so on..

So, my X-axis has two groupings - clients and month(s) in the last quarter. Also, revenue is further stacked against products. So, I am kinda merging two different datasets - Revenue measure for each Client, months, product against Meetings' measure for each Client, month to construct the chart.

A sample program that I'd created for generating the chart:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.LineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class GroupedStackedBarLineChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    public GroupedStackedBarLineChart(final String title) {
        super(title);
        // final JFreeChart chart = constructBarOverLineChart();
        final JFreeChart chart = constructLineOverBarChart();
        final ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    private JFreeChart constructLineOverBarChart() {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "Stacked Grouped Bar Line Chart", "Products/Month",
                "Meetings/Month", fetchMeetingDataSet(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);


        final KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product1)", "Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product2)", "Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product3)", "Jan13");

        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product1)", "Feb13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product2)", "Feb13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product3)", "Feb13");

        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product1)", "Mar13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product2)", "Mar13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product3)", "Mar13");

        final GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);
        renderer.setItemMargin(0.076);

        final SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Products/Month");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Jan13");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Feb13");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Mar13");

        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.28);

        final CategoryPlot subPlot1 = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        subPlot1.setDataset(1, fetchRevenueDataSet());
        subPlot1.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        final ValueAxis revenueAxis = new NumberAxis("Revenue");
        subPlot1.setRangeAxis(1, revenueAxis);
        subPlot1.setRenderer(1, renderer);

        return chart;
    }

    private JFreeChart constructBarOverLineChart() {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Stacked Grouped Bar Line Chart", "Clients", "Revenue",
                fetchRevenueDataSet(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
                false);

        final KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product1)", "Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product2)", "Jan13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Jan13 (Product3)", "Jan13");

        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product1)", "Feb13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product2)", "Feb13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Feb13 (Product3)", "Feb13");

        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product1)", "Mar13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product2)", "Mar13");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Mar13 (Product3)", "Mar13");

        final GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);
        renderer.setItemMargin(0.076);

        final SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Products/Month");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Jan13");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Feb13");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Mar13");

        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.28);

        final CategoryPlot subPlot1 = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        subPlot1.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        subPlot1.setRenderer(renderer);

        final ValueAxis meetingAxis = new NumberAxis("Meetings");
        subPlot1.setDataset(1, fetchMeetingDataSet());
        // subPlot1.mapDatasetToDomainAxis(1, 1);
        subPlot1.setRangeAxis(1, meetingAxis);
        subPlot1.setRangeAxisLocation(0, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        subPlot1.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
        subPlot1.setRenderer(1, new LineAndShapeRenderer(true, false));


        return chart;
    }

    private CategoryDataset fetchRevenueDataSet() {

        final DefaultCategoryDataset revenueDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        revenueDataSet.addValue(20.3, "Jan13 (Product1)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(27.2, "Jan13 (Product2)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.7, "Jan13 (Product3)", "Client1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.4, "Feb13 (Product1)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(10.9, "Feb13 (Product2)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(18.4, "Feb13 (Product3)", "Client1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.5, "Mar13 (Product1)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.9, "Mar13 (Product2)", "Client1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.1, "Mar13 (Product3)", "Client1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.3, "Jan13 (Product1)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.2, "Jan13 (Product2)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(28.7, "Jan13 (Product3)", "Client2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(12.7, "Feb13 (Product1)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(17.9, "Feb13 (Product2)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(12.6, "Feb13 (Product3)", "Client2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.4, "Mar13 (Product1)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(21.0, "Mar13 (Product2)", "Client2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(11.1, "Mar13 (Product3)", "Client2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.8, "Jan13 (Product1)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.4, "Jan13 (Product2)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.3, "Jan13 (Product3)", "Client3");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(11.9, "Feb13 (Product1)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(31.0, "Feb13 (Product2)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(22.7, "Feb13 (Product3)", "Client3");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.3, "Mar13 (Product1)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(14.4, "Mar13 (Product2)", "Client3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(25.3, "Mar13 (Product3)", "Client3");

        return revenueDataSet;
    }

    private CategoryDataset fetchMeetingDataSet() {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset meetingDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        meetingDataSet.addValue(20, "Jan13", "Client1");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(8, "Feb13", "Client1");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(35, "Mar13", "Client1");

        meetingDataSet.addValue(7, "Jan13", "Client2");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(20, "Feb13", "Client2");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(12, "Mar13", "Client2");

        meetingDataSet.addValue(25, "Jan13", "Client3");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(17, "Feb13", "Client3");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(7, "Mar13", "Client3");

        return meetingDataSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupedStackedBarLineChart demo = new GroupedStackedBarLineChart(
                "Client Revenue and Meetings");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The output of the above program does not show the chart as is required. Instead, the line chart shows `P` meetings for *Jan13* with `Client1`, `Q` meetings for *Jan13* with `Client2`, `R` meetings for *Jan13* with `Client3` and `X` meetings for *Feb13* with `Client2`, `Y` meetings for *Feb13* with `Client2` and so on.. That is, grouping for the client is not respected. I tried varying the row-key/column-key in the line chart dataset with no yield.

Could you please point me towards getting the line chart correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to upload a simple jpg show-casing the chart I am developing as I do not have 10 reputation points yet :(

Comment: Maybe cite an [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), by name, post a link to the picture, or edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can create a multiaxis chart using Ireport, I had this similar requirement.

Comment: @trashgod - I'd uploaded and attached image link.

Comment: @Sharad - Multiaxis chart does not work well for a grouped chart. You would be shown line for each combination of the grouping defined in the shared domain axis

Comment: @Saiyyer: You might look among the _overlaid charts_ in the [JWS demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Comment: @trashgod - I've attached a sample program wherein I'd added an range axis showing the meetings over the GroupedStackedBarChart showing revenue. I hope this clarifies the issue for which I am soliciting your help.

Comment: +1 so you can upload images soon

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); sorry, I don't understand the desired result.

Comment: @trashgod - I corrected the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to implement a custom renderer - a mixture out of GroupStackedBarRenderer and LineAndShapeRenderer - but the following fake-grouping was easier ;)

So I've replaced the GroupedStackedBarRenderer with a StackeBarRenderer and inserted a dummy column between the groups.
The grouped category labels for the clients were archieved by a second domain axis -
lucky enough, the labels of the 2nd category axis are centered within the groups of the first axis no matter how many clients/groups are used ...

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.text.G2TextMeasurer;
import org.jfree.text.TextBlock;
import org.jfree.text.TextUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class GroupedStackedBarLineChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    public GroupedStackedBarLineChart(final String title) {
        super(title);
        // final JFreeChart chart = constructBarOverLineChart();
        final JFreeChart chart = constructLineOverBarChart();
        final ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    private JFreeChart constructLineOverBarChart() {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "Stacked Grouped Bar Line Chart", "",
                "Meetings/Month", fetchMeetingDataSet(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        final StackedBarRenderer renderer = new StackedBarRenderer();
        renderer.setItemMargin(0.076);

        final CategoryPlot cp = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        cp.setDataset(1, fetchRevenueDataSet());
        final ValueAxis revenueAxis = new NumberAxis("Revenue");
        cp.setRangeAxis(1, revenueAxis);
        cp.setRenderer(1, renderer);

        chopCategoryLabels(cp);
        insertFakeGrouping(cp);

        CategoryAxis ca = new CategoryAxis("Products/Month");
        cp.setDomainAxis(1, ca);
        cp.setDataset(2, anotherDataSet());
        cp.mapDatasetToDomainAxis(2, 1);
        cp.setDomainAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        ca.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        ca.setTickMarksVisible(false);


        return chart;
    }

    private void insertFakeGrouping(CategoryPlot cp) {
        for (int i=0; i<cp.getDatasetCount(); i++) {
            assert(cp.getDataset(i) instanceof DefaultCategoryDataset);
            CategoryDataset cd = cp.getDataset(i);
            Comparable<?> firstRow = cd.getRowKey(0);

            DefaultCategoryDataset dcd = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            for (int col=0; col<cd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                if (col > 0) {
                    String c1 = cd.getColumnKey(col-1).toString();
                    c1 = c1.substring(c1.indexOf('_'));
                    String c2 = cd.getColumnKey(col).toString();
                    c2 = c2.substring(c2.indexOf('_'));
                    if (!c1.equals(c2)) {
                        dcd.addValue(null, firstRow, "dummy"+col);
                    }
                }
                for (int row=0; row<cd.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    Comparable<?> rowKey = cd.getRowKey(row);
                    Comparable<?> columnKey = cd.getColumnKey(col);
                    dcd.addValue(cd.getValue(rowKey, columnKey), rowKey, columnKey);
                }
            }

            cp.setDataset(i, dcd);
        }
    }


    private void chopCategoryLabels(CategoryPlot cp) {
        CategoryAxis caOld = cp.getDomainAxis();
        CategoryAxis caNew = new CategoryAxis(){
            protected TextBlock createLabel(Comparable category, float width,
                RectangleEdge edge, Graphics2D g2) {
                String cat = category.toString();
                cat = (cat.contains("_"))
                    ? cat.substring(0, cat.indexOf('_'))
                    : "";
                TextBlock label = TextUtilities.createTextBlock(cat,
                getTickLabelFont(category), getTickLabelPaint(category), width,
                getMaximumCategoryLabelLines(), new G2TextMeasurer(g2));
                return label;
            }           
        };

        try {
            new PropertyUtilsBean().copyProperties(caNew, caOld);
            cp.setDomainAxis(0, caNew);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not really?", e);
        }
    }

    private CategoryDataset anotherDataSet() {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset ds = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        ds.addValue(1, "1", "Client 1");
        ds.addValue(1, "2", "Client 2");
        ds.addValue(1, "3", "Client 3");
        return ds;
    }

    private CategoryDataset fetchRevenueDataSet() {

        final DefaultCategoryDataset revenueDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        revenueDataSet.addValue(20.3, "Product 1", "Jan13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(27.2, "Product 2", "Jan13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.7, "Product 3", "Jan13_1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.4, "Product 1", "Feb13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(10.9, "Product 2", "Feb13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(18.4, "Product 3", "Feb13_1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.5, "Product 1", "Mar13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.9, "Product 2", "Mar13_1");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.1, "Product 3", "Mar13_1");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.3, "Product 1", "Jan13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(16.2, "Product 2", "Jan13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(28.7, "Product 3", "Jan13_2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(12.7, "Product 1", "Feb13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(17.9, "Product 2", "Feb13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(12.6, "Product 3", "Feb13_2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.4, "Product 1", "Mar13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(21.0, "Product 2", "Mar13_2");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(11.1, "Product 3", "Mar13_2");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.8, "Product 1", "Jan13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(23.4, "Product 2", "Jan13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(19.3, "Product 3", "Jan13_3");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(11.9, "Product 1", "Feb13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(31.0, "Product 2", "Feb13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(22.7, "Product 3", "Feb13_3");

        revenueDataSet.addValue(15.3, "Product 1", "Mar13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(14.4, "Product 2", "Mar13_3");
        revenueDataSet.addValue(25.3, "Product 3", "Mar13_3");

        return revenueDataSet;
    }

    private CategoryDataset fetchMeetingDataSet() {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset meetingDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        meetingDataSet.addValue(20, "Meetings", "Jan13_1");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(8, "Meetings", "Feb13_1");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(35, "Meetings", "Mar13_1");

        meetingDataSet.addValue(7, "Meetings", "Jan13_2");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(20, "Meetings", "Feb13_2");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(12, "Meetings", "Mar13_2");

        meetingDataSet.addValue(25, "Meetings", "Jan13_3");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(17, "Meetings", "Feb13_3");
        meetingDataSet.addValue(7, "Meetings", "Mar13_3");

        return meetingDataSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupedStackedBarLineChart demo = new GroupedStackedBarLineChart(
                "Client Revenue and Meetings");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, We revisited our report design and tweaked it a bit to fit in available Jasper reports. but @kiwiwings, your hack works perfectly. Thanks much for your solution.